# What's oscillatory instability in the delay differential equations?

Tags: control, control-system, math, stability, frequency-response

Does DDE’s stability depend on forcing term and ODE’s stability does not depend?If yes, then is frequency analysis of stability applicable only to DDE and not ODE?

In control systems, we study frequency analysis of stability and i want to have an intuitive understanding. I understand Bounded Input, Bounded Output(BIBO).But,  How does one go from BIBO to frequency methods? My conjecture is that frequency methods of stability makes sense only in DDE, not ODE. Am I right?

Comment: Shouldn't this be a math SE question? Maybe you can explain why not. Just because some EEs need to solve DDEs doesn't necessarily mean that questions on the type of coffee they drink are relevant on this site.

Comment: I am trying to understand the origin of frequency methods used in control system. How is Bounded Input Bounded output stability related to frequency methods?

Comment: @Andyaka sorry most mathematicians will look at you cross eyed if you ask them what BIBO stability is. This is defined within the realm of Control System Engineering and the closest realm within the SE that Controls falls under is EE.

Answer (score 0):

Stability based on frequency response methods like Bode Plots, Nichols etc. assumes that the system is linear and so a stable system ideally is considered stable regardless of the size of the input.

BIBO stability on the other hand considers that the system might be nonlinear. That for some inputs the system output might be bounded, but for other inputs not so.

All linear stable systems are BIBO stable. But not all BIBO stable systems are linear.